# Adding R-values in regression split by group

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, regression

I have this dataframe:

```
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggplot2)

x <- runif(300, min=1, max=5)
y <- runif(300, min=1, max=5)
Cond <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
df <- data.frame(x,y,Cond)
attach(df)
Cond <- as.factor(Cond)
```

And I'm making a scatterplot with a regression line containing geom points and the geom_smooth line coloured by condition:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, colour = Cond))+
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label))), size = 6)+
  stat_poly_line()+
  geom_point(size = 3, position = position_jitter(0.05))
```

The code does not work as well for my made-up dataset, but you can see the end result here: [image]

I want to add a grand regression line and include the R-squared value for all the data points. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only apply the color aesthetic to the layers where you need it, and add another call for the line and equation that doesn't separate the data into groups. First I made a dummy data set:

```
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

set.seed(50)
 
# create the variance covariance matrix
sigma<-rbind(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5), c(0.8, 1, 0.7, 0.6), c(0.8, 0.7, 1, 0.7), c(0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 1))
 
# create the mean vector
mu <- c(9, 13, 12, 14) 
 
# generate the multivariate normal distribution
df<-as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n=100, mu=mu, Sigma=sigma)) %>% 
  rename("x_A" = 1,
         "x_B" = 2,
         "y_A" = 3,
         "y_B" = 4) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
    names_pattern = "(.)_(.)")
```

Then the plot with the new call for the general trend line and equation:

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = x,
           y = y)) +
  
    geom_point(aes(color = set),
             size = 2) +
  
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(afterlabel = paste(after_stat(eq.label))),
                   color = set), 
               size = 6, 
               label.y = c(0.7, 0.8)) +
  
  stat_poly_line(aes(color = set, fill = set)) +
  
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label))),
               size = 6,
               label.y = 0.9,
               color = "black") +

  stat_poly_line(color = "black") +
   
  theme_bw()
```

And this is the resulting plot:

[image]